# Фокус в ListView (GridView) ломает работу GridSplitter

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Компонент а-ля "total commander". В нем используется 2 панели, в каждой из которых ListView+GridView, который привязан к списку. Между ними GridSplitter.

GridSplitter работает, но при изменении списка (ItemsSource) ListView теряет фокус. С помощью SelectedItem устанавливается выделенный элемент в новом списке, но не фокус.

Путем долгого гугления выяснил, что нужно вручную установить фокус на нужный элемент. И поскольку используется биндинг, то нахожу нужный ListViewItem и делаю на нем фокус. ListView ведет себя правильно... но это ломает GridSplitter - его как бы цементирует, не сдвинуть.

Воспроизводимый пример

```
<Window
    x:Class="GridSplitterBug.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridSplitterBug"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="800" Height="450" mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneTime}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Username}" Header="имя" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>    
        <GridSplitter
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Background="Black" ResizeDirection="Columns" />    
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

code-behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            MyList.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
            Items.Add(new Item(){Username = "foo", Lastname = "bar"});
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        private void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MyList.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
            {
                var dataObject = MyList.Items[0];
                var iv = MyList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataObject) as ListViewItem;
                //Keyboard.Focus(iv);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
    }
```

Если раскомментировать `//Keyboard.Focus(iv);` то все сломается.

Как это вообще может быть? И как починить? Может я неправильно использую ItemContainerGenerator? но у меня вышло только так, иначе он все время возвращает null.

**update**: Уточню суть.

В total commander есть навигация клавишами - перемещаемся по списку, enter - вход в папку, backspace - на уровень выше. При входе/выходе перегружаем список и запоминаем SelectedItem для восстановления.

Но проблема не в том, чтобы выставить текущий элемент после обновления списка. Проблема в том, что этот текущий элемент не получает автоматом фокус клавиатуры (а без этого нажатие клавиши навигации работает не там), приходится искать этот элемент и вручную делать на него фокус.

Но после выставления фокуса цементируется GridSplitter между панелями.

В примере нет обновления списка - ведь разницы нет, любая установка фоукса на пункт ListView цементирует GridSplitter.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, GridSplitter "цементируется" из-за того, что начало движения сплитера также вызывает `ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged`, в обработчике которого я нахожу текущий элемент, делаю на нем фокус клавиатуры, а сплитер теряет свой фокус и возвращается на начальную позицию.

С фокусом же, если не хочется выключать виртуализацию, все оказалось сложно. Ведь нужный ListViewItem может просто не существовать на момент, когда он нужен.

После кучи опытов в попытке усидеть на 2х стульях удалось лучшее решение, которое удалось найти, такое (главное это `DispatcherPriority.Loaded`):

```
public FilesListView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FileList.SelectionChanged += FileList_SelectionChanged;
}

private void FileList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FileList.ScrollIntoView(FileList.SelectedItem);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, 
               new DispatcherOperationCallback(Callback), null);
}

private object Callback(object arg)
{
    if (FileList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(FileList.SelectedItem) is ListViewItem iv)
    {
        iv.Focus(); нужно ли???
        Keyboard.Focus(iv);
    }
    return arg;
}
```

Лучшее, но не идеальное. Если быстро обновлять список, то есть низкий, но не равный нулю шанс "срыва фокуса". Ищу вариант улучшения.

ps: если запущено из под студии, то шанс "срыва фокуса" сильно возрастает - в зависимости от того, насколько активно пишутся данные в `output`, поэтому проверять нужно без отладчика, иначе можно долго гадать почему так плохо работает.